# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. using @RequestParam in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I made a simple form when button is clicked the form values send to the controller and set in the second view. But when i click the button it is giving me the error

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admissionform")
public class StudentAdmissionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/form.html", method = GET)
    public ModelAndView getStudentForm() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("StudentForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/submit.html", method = POST)
    public ModelAndView submitStudentForm(@RequestParam("name") String name, 
                                          @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("SubmitForm");
        model.addObject("msg", "Name is : "+name + " Password is : " + password);
        return model;
    }
}
```

StudentForm:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Student Form</title>
</head>
<body>          

        <div class="modal-body" id="main-body">
            <form action="submit.html" method="post">
                <div>
                        <label>Email address:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div >
                        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                        <input id="pwd" name="password">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

SubmitForm:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Submitted</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>${msg}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me what is the mistake that i am doing in the code. I shall be thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default parameters annotated with `@RequestParam` are mandatory. So, those parameters should be present in client requests. In your `submitStudentForm` method you have two required parameters named `name` and `password`:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView submitStudentForm(@RequestParam("name") String name, 
                                      @RequestParam("password") String password) { ... }
```

Then you should pass those parameters with the exact same names in your from. Currently, you're passing the `password` parameter:

```
<div>
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input id="pwd" name="password">      
</div>
```

But failing to do so for the unfortunate `name` parameter. I guess you should rename the `email` parameter to `name`:

```
div>
    <label>Email address:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="name">
</div>
```

For more info, you can checkout the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestparam).